# How do I handle Import Errors?

Tags: python, error-handling, scikit-learn

I got this error when trying to run a python file with:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

The error is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ThreadPool' from 'multiprocessing.pool' (/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py)
```

However, when I execute the same line from the terminal as:

```
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

it works without any error.

Any idea what might cause this error? and how to fix it?

Comment: whats the file's name?

Comment: Do you have any files in your working directory named `multiprocessing.py`? that could mangle the names when it is trying to import things. If there is, try renaming your files to something else.

Comment: @khuynh No I did not have a file with this name but I had a file named queue.py somehow it was the reason and when I renamed it the other file worked without any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly, these errors are caused by naming of other and current scripts with the names of library files. So renaming these helps you handle the error.